# Matches in binary columns-R

Tags: r, prediction, predict

I am performing some prediction models. I have 2 binary columns , one with predicted values and the other one with the actual values.

Since the columns have few ones because it counts the number of  people with cancer, i want to observe how many cases the model detected(how many real ones it predicted) and the percentage of sick persons correctly predicted.

Brief description of the data: the first column shows the real values and the seconde one shows the predicted values:

```
> predictedvsreal
         real prediction
39240       0    0
39241       0    0
39242       0    0
39243       1    0
39244       0    1
39245       0    0
39246       0    0
39247       0    0
39248       1    1
39249       0    0
39250       0    0
39251       0    0
39252       0    0
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and the desired output for that input. That way we can easily test possible solutions.

Comment: Some sample data and a demonstration of what you have tried would be very helpful [see here for more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In the meantime, you probably want to be looking at `table`

Comment: `with(your_data, table(your_first_column_name, your_second_column_name))`

Comment: @Gregor you're spot on... that should be an answer, IMO

Comment: What is the class of your data, not a data frame? If you post `dput(head(your_data))` everything will be much clearer...

Comment: You keep editing and not addressing the problem. Please type (or copy/paste)`dput(head(predictedvsreal))` into your R console. Then copy the output which will look something like `structure(list(c(0, 0, ...` and paste it into your question. Format it as code.

Answer (score 1):

Next time *please* include a reproducible example as it makes the question much better - both for letting people who answer have a concrete example to work with and to catch edge-cases, and for future readers to see a real example.

There are lots of good recommendations for how to create nice, minimal, reproducible examples [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

From what you describe, you want the `table` function, probably like this:

```
with(your_data, table(your_first_column_name, your_second_column_name))
```